# How do I put Admob interstitials on a timer for ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, ads, interstitial

I am trying to implement Admob interstitials into my Xcode project and I want to set it so an ad pops up every 70 seconds or so while a user is using the app.  If anyone could explain how to do this, or respond with a link to a guide it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You want to display ad at every 70 seconds while app is active? You want to do this I am right

Answer (score 1):

Load the ad when starting the app/activity/scene. Keep a timer of 70 seconds after which show the ad. 
The ad will be displayed. If user presses it or cancels it, in both cases you will have to create new adRequest for the ad to be shown after 140 seconds. Maybe you can have a loop. But i am not sure this is the recommended way to use interstitials. I think they should be shown once during one screen. Show it at a stage when the user will definitely read the ad.